# Why does reducing the 'Pricing Tier (Scale QPUs)' of my Azure Analysis Model, also reduce the memory usage?

Tags: azure, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

When I change the pricing tier of my Azure Analysis Model from S9 to S4, the memory usage of the model decreases (purple line).

[image]

I would have expected the green (Hard memory limit) and the blue line (High memory limit) to drop, but not the actual memory usage of the model to drop (purple).

The model data seems to be fine, but there is a drop from 57GB to 16GB.

**Why does reducing the 'Pricing Tier (Scale QPUs)' of my Azure Analysis Model, also reduce the memory usage?**

Comment: My assumption would be the amount used for query caching, though struggling to find anything concrete online.

Comment: @iamdave Yea same, I've seen this happen a few times, but can't find any literature about it online.

Comment: I think you would see the same behavior if you just paused and resumed your server without scaling down. It is clearing various caches in memory.